nx vue-monorepo build fails due to loading eslint config from plugins inside node modules
I am trying to migrate a large vue project to monorepo.
I managed to run command for starting local development server:
> nx run texasholdem:dev
> vite --mode localdev

VITE v5.0.12  ready in 1267 ms

However during build:local command it seems that plugin eslint is tring to load config from package inside node_modules:
> nx run texasholdem:build-local
> vue-tsc --build --force
> vite build --mode localdev

[vite-plugin-pwa:build] Failed to load config "@ljharb" to extend from.
Referenced from: C:\Users\lukXmelo\Documents\GitHub\texasholdem\node_modules\qs\.eslintrc
file: C:/Users/lukXmelo/Documents/GitHub/texasholdem/node_modules/qs/lib/index.js

I also tried removing plugin vite-plugin-pwa, but then there is an error in another package:
[commonjs--resolver] Failed to load config "@ljharb" to extend from.
Referenced from: C:\Users\lukXmelo\Documents\GitHub\texasholdem\node_modules\qs\.eslintrc
file: C:/Users/lukXmelo/Documents/GitHub/texasholdem/node_modules/qs/lib/index.js

In this project packages qs, chroma.js and eslint-config-airbnb have custom eslintrc configuration files...
I added node_modules to ignoredPatterns in eslintrc.js and also to .eslintignore as recommended in:
https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/5671

Fixed by adding node_modules to ignore list of eslint in vite.config.ts:
plugins: [
    checker({ typescript: true }),
    eslintPlugin({
      exclude: ['/virtual:/**', /node_modules/],
    }),
    ... other plugins
]

